# Import requests error in spite of requests installed

Tags: python

I have the following error: when I execute my code :

```
python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Checks already done :

1. `pip list cmd result` => seems OK

   ```
   pip (7.1.0)
   requests (2.7.0) => OK
   setuptools (12.0.5)
   wheel (0.24.0)
   ```
2. Cmd results :

   ```
   pip install requests
   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
   ```

=> seems OK.

3. `ls cmd` confirms that the package in that folder.

   ```
   README              requests
   __pycache__         requests-2.7.0.dist-info
   _markerlib          setuptools
   easy_install.py         setuptools-12.0.5.dist-info
   pip             wheel
   pip-7.1.0.dist-info     wheel-0.24.0.dist-info
   pkg_resources
   ```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the code in python 3.4 and by accident you don't have multiple python versions on your system? As you might know, you could print the version with: `import sys
print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 1):

Please add output of `python --version` and `import sys ; print(sys.path)` in the question. You

- most likely have multiple Python installations on your operating system
- pip install installs the requests in one of the installations
- ... but python command you try to run Python with modules from another installation

Please use [virtualenv and Python package installation guide to create an isolated Python environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments), so you know which modules are installed there and if there was any issue installing them.

Comment: OR you can remove the unneeded pythons: 
RUN:  "rpm -q -f /usr/local/bin/python2.7"
If the package was found use "yum" to remove else "rm -rf"